# Is there way to get "Follow up" details of email of Exchange Email Account using ews?

Tags: .net, email, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I have email application. I download emails of the Exchange Server Emails accounts using EWS. I get everything including attachment. I want to get follow up details.

How can I get details of "Follow up" attached with email?

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the Message Flags if so you can use the Flags property https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.flag_members(v=exchg.80).aspx which will correspond to whether its flagged for followup. If you want the Name of the flag being used you need to use the FlagRequest named prop eg

```
        ExtendedPropertyDefinition FlagRequest = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(DefaultExtendedPropertySet.Common, 0x8530, MapiPropertyType.String);
        PropertySet FlagPropset = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
        FlagPropset.Add(FlagRequest);
        ItemView ivItemViewp = new ItemView(1);
        ivItemViewp.PropertySet = FlagPropset;
        EmailMessage lastemail = (EmailMessage)service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, ivItemViewp).Items[0];
        if (lastemail.Flag.FlagStatus == ItemFlagStatus.Flagged)
        {
            Object FlagRequestVal = null;
            if (lastemail.TryGetProperty(FlagRequest, out FlagRequestVal))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(FlagRequestVal.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Cheers
Glen